# Does the phosphoric acid in drinks lead to leaching chromium from stainless steel 316?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I had considered using a small [SS 316](https://www.aalco.co.uk/datasheets/Stainless-Steel-14401-316-Bar-and-Section_37.ashx) pipe as a straw for sodas. Question being, would the phosphoric acid in drinks leach out chromium, and if so would it be carcinogenic? Hexavalent chromium is considerably carcinogenic.

Comment: It is pretty hard to oxidize chromium to Cr (VI) and phosphoric acid is not an oxidizing agent. If you check the chemical compatibility chart of SS 316, phosphoric acid is *not* recommended to be used with SS 316. Regardless of Cr, sodas are far more dangerous in terms of sugar content/artificalsweetners, than chromium or its compounds. Human body was not meant to consume *free* phosphoric acid, otherwise Nature would have provided it in fruits.

Comment: Many years in corrosion and never encountered leaching of chrome from stainless.  Some operations included moving hot super phosphoric acid around in 316 L lined rail cars.

Comment: The point of stainless steel is being highly resistant to acids...

Comment: Not all stainless steel are resistant to acids. SS 316 in question is an example.

Comment: I would say all are resistant, not immune  Concentrated nitric has no affect on 13 Cr  ( at least during a spot test).

Comment: @blacksmith37 Sometimes dilute acids will corrode, and stronger versions cause passivation

Comment: I don't think that whatever would or could leach from these pipes would be more hazardous than the drinks themselves. At least not in the concentrations expected from the leach process.

Answer (score -2):

Technically, Phosphoric acid in drinks is not leaching Chromium from your Stainless Steel, but is contributing agent to its gradual galvanic corrosion. The process requires an anodic metal (found in steel alloy), source of H+ (acid presence), oxygen (air exposure) and a electrolyte (from the dissolved salts in the drink are the electrolyte.

Usually the corrosion takes some time (as in the case of my steak knives which were the victim of so-called [pit corrosion](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/P-Pistorius/publication/243687929_Metastable_Pitting_Corrosion_of_Stainless_Steel_and_the_Transition_to_Stability/links/0c9605357034e23362000000/Metastable-Pitting-Corrosion-of-Stainless-Steel-and-the-Transition-to-Stability.pdf) from cutting a mango apparently rich in ascorbic acid ([discussed here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12540-016-5684-7)) that were left sitting in the sink for a few days), actually, more like a consequence of neglect.

Now the case with phosphoric acid drinks is more interesting because normally they have a dark coloration. The latter implies dyes which in sunlight generally possess some [photocatalytic abilities](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.est.6b00213). The latter can introduce solvated electrons and electron holes leading to radical formation with water (hydroxyl radical) and in this case with phosphoric acid, the [phosphoric radical](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/jcsc/097/05-06/0573-0580), which also could potentially be more active here than your drinks original dilute phosphoric acid.

Good news is that since this is electrochemical reaction, it is the iron metal (likely the most anodic metal present) which first corrodes (forming deeply colored iron salts) and not per se, the chromium metal (albeit, it may eventually be attacked when the Fe is depleted).

So basically you had all the required set of reagents (and may be even catalytic lighting) for a nice galvanic corrosion experiment, although completely unintended.

Comment: Ascorbic acid does not corrode stainles steel.

Comment: Thanks for reading my answer and your comment reflects the need for a source (apparently other my personally observed issue with my stainless steel steak knives) which I have now inserted with other sources as well. Note, the role of NaCl per the technical reference as well (likely in the drink).

Comment: Relating to Ascorbic acid/NaCl corroding stainless steel, may I suggest PICTURES here http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=152955#pid620207 .

Comment: More technically correct, Ascorbic acid (A.A ) with NaCl in tap water with A.A at higher  concentrations may induce a chelating effect resulting in severe pit corrosion here.

Comment: With respect to my answer to the question, it remains correct, the reported corrosion is not the action of any one acid. Likely a more complex pathway leading to an assisted corrosion action.

Comment: Note, this is not a matter for a corroding acid as noted above, to quote: "Many years in corrosion and never encountered leaching of chrome from stainless. Some operations included moving hot super phosphoric acid around in 316 L lined rail cars. – 
blacksmith37" which is clearly supports, instead, the literature noting a complex galvanic corrosion pathway for stainless steel with, for example, fruit acids and NaCl in transition rich tap water, and here via another acid.